# What does the localize button in Xcode do?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, localization, helpshift

I am working on a Unity3d game for iOS which uses the Helpshift plugin for customer support.

- Unity version : 4.6.4p1.
- Xcode version : 6.1.1

The problem is that the popup for the plugin appears without any buttons.

But this gets fixed if one selects the .strings file on the plugin and click on the localize button. It then places the files in the lproj folder of that language.

But the localize functionality is surely doing more than just putting it in the correct folder, as even if you put it in the folder before hand the problem persists.

One can also see that after pressing the localize button, the number of files localized in the info panel of the project in Xcode increases by one.

I cannot have this setup as the build is automated, one cannot have any manual steps in the process as it will completely break the work flow.

Do let me know if you have any leads, if not the complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, clicking the localize button does do more than just put a strings file in a folder.  That is the main part, but it will also wire that folder and file up into the project as a resource that gets included during the build process and will likely add some reference in the storyboard as well.

See [Internationalizing the User Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html)